# although ios 6.1 as base sdk xcode 5 build ipa for ios 7

Tags: ios7, xcode5, ipa, ios6.1

i changed the base sdk for iOS 6.1 in xcode 5 .

When i simulate my project on a iOS 6.1 simulator or on a iOS 6.1 device
all works fine. But when i build a ipa and install it on a iOS 7 device
the device use the iOS 7 sdk and my hole app looks weird. I changed my base
sdk for iOS 6.1, so why use my device the iOS 7 sdk?

I read that iOS 7 use the iOS 6.1 sdk for old published apps.
What do i have to do that iOS 7 also do that for my app?
My only idea is to install xcode 4 again...

Answer (score 6):

I have experienced the same problem - unfortunately only discovered AFTER submitting to the app store and the app being approved and released, causing all sorts of mayhem due to interface glitches.

The issue occurs due to a bug in XCode 5 (including in XCode 5.0.2 it seems) that is triggered when you install older SDKs.

When you have multiple SDKs installed, you will see that when you connect your device to XCode, there are multiple entries for your device, with no way to tell them apart. But it appears that the TOP entry is for the OLDEST SDK you have installed, the BOTTOM one for the NEWEST SDK.

I have found that if I first use "Test" project option to run the app on the device with the SDK I want to use (in my case the top entry, which is for iOS6.1 SDK), then that is the SDK that will subsequently be used when I archive the app.

Comment: Wow, how did you ever figure this out? Thanks! The seeming randomness of my app appearing between iOS6/7 look & feel was driving me mad!

Comment: Apple will require compiling against iOS7 SDK as of Feb 2014, so if you are intending to publish your app, installing older SDKs has become pointless. I guess this is why Apple hasn't addressed this "bug" - their intention was that devs stick to using only the latest SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can have both xcode 5 and 4.6.3 installed.

Also a lot of post say that in the simulator it look iOS7 but on device it will look iOS6.1 if you set the base sdk to 6.1

see:

[Is it possible to install iOS 6 SDK on Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5)

[Do apple allow custom iOS 5/6 style UI for iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776627/do-apple-allow-custom-ios-5-6-style-ui-for-ios7)